# Open a pdf in a modal using Intel XDK

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pdf, cordova-3, intel-xdk

I am trying to open a pdf document from a html link in intel xdk.

I am trying to do this by opening the pdf in a modal with an iframe element in it. Unfortunately that isn't working the phones.

Here is the code :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

            <div class="modal outer-element uib_w_20" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/modal" data-ver="1" data-backdrop="true" id="popShowHref">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">
                                <span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> Notice</span>
                            </h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="col uib_col_12 single-col" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                                <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                                    <form>
                                        <iframe height="200" width="200" src="http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/riccardo/courses/cs6750-fa09/talks/Ellis-elliptic-curve-crypto.pdf"></iframe>
                                    </form>
                                    <!--<span class="uib_shim"></span>-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The above code isn't working. When I am opening this in XDK emulator, its asking me to download the pdf, but when I am opening this in phone, I do not get any option and the iframe remains blank!

The code is using bootstrap.

Any solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Cordova In-App-Browser to open external files, it will open a modal window and load the url

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script>           

function openIAB(){
    var url = "http://somewebsite.com/file.pdf";
    window.open(url, "_blank", "location=yes");
}            
        </script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="openIAB()">Open PDF</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

make sure you have checked the In-App-Browser plugin in Project Settings -> Plugins

Comment: It doesn't work that way. In-app browser was not able to open the pdf in my android phone. I had to use the google docs method with the in-app browser to get it working.